# How do I remove the select option black border in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, select, sass, border

As shown in the picture below,

black border is shown when the select option is hover from the chrome.

how can I remove the border?

[image]

The code below didn't work.

```
select{

  &:hover,
  &:focus 
  {
    outline: 0 !important;
  }
}
```

I'd appreciate it if you could help me solve the problem.

Comment: Can you please provide minimal reproducible code? The default selection option has no border/outline for selection.

Comment: It was a Chrome update issue. The problem has been resolved..! Thank you :)

Comment: Glad that it is working now. Thanks for informing. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go [chrome flags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqpH8.png)
2. Disable [#form-controls-refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3owhx.png)

Comment: UI is back as it used to be. Thank you for your kind explanation :) !

Comment: This is only for you, however.  If you're trying to design a website, this doesn't fix the problem for anybody else.

Answer (score 2):

It happen when chrome updated. Actually, it it's a update feature from chromium that update in 2020.
If you interested know about more feature below this link.

**https://blog.chromium.org/2020/03/updates-to-form-controls-and-focus.html**

**#Problem solution:**

### Just go to below this link

**chrome://flags/#form-controls-refresh**

and **Disabled** Web Platform Controls updated UI
[image]