# How can I remove the select option black border in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome

In the latest version of chrome(version:83), it is getting a black border in the select option. Is there any ways to fix it? I fixed the out-line issues of text box and buttons using the following styles

```
*,*:focus,*:hover{
outline:none !important;
```

}

I checked the issue [How do I remove the select option black border in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62013064/how-do-i-remove-the-select-option-black-border-in-chrome) and it says the issue was due to the chrome update. Can we fix it using css?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove the select option black border in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62013064/how-do-i-remove-the-select-option-black-border-in-chrome)

Comment: @LuudJacobs, thanks for your update. No, by disabling that flag only disables it on our machine.

Comment: There is a thread about this issue on the google support forums. It does not offer a solution (yet), but might be interesting for you to follow. Many people seem to be displeased with this problem so let's hope google provides the ability to overwrite this styling in the future at least. https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/48974735?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

I've tried my hardest in fixing the problem. The newest Chrome update has "upgraded" form handling in the browser. My suggestion was to add `outline: none;`, but that only works on `<input />`, `<textarea>` and `<button>` elements. As seen everywhere, there is something about disabling a flag, but if you want your site to go out to the public (webserver), this won't work, as disabling that flag only disables it on your computer. I really hope that Google fixes this issue, but they don't seem to notice the number of people complaining about this.

Comment: thanks for your update.  Yes, i also tried a lot but nothing works.

Comment: Yeah, I do not think it should be easy to fix it with a `<select>` element, but the other one's do work (including `<a>`).